# Sharedpreferences не правильно загружает данные

Tags: android, android-studio, android-shared-preferences

Стоит задача:

В первом активти есть `saveText()` и `saveTexts()` который сохраняют  текстовые данные

```
 private void saveText() {
    MyPTv = getSharedPreferences("MyPTv", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor tv20 = MyPTv.edit();
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = MyPTv.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, randoms.getText().toString());
    tv20.putString(SAVED_Tv20, name_client.getText().toString());
    tv20.putString(SAVED_Tv21, datatimepos.getText().toString());
    tv20.putString(SAVED_Tv22, timeposh.getText().toString());
    tv20.putString(SAVED_Tv23, timezakr.getText().toString());
   tv20.commit();

}
```

И еще один:

```
 private void saveTexts() {
    sPrefss = getSharedPreferences("MyOfice", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor tv25 = sPrefss.edit();       
    tv25.putString(SAVED_T, datatimepos.getText().toString());
    tv25.putString(SAVED_Tv, timeposh.getText().toString());
    tv25.putString(SAVED_Tv2, timezakr.getText().toString()); 
    tv25.commit();
    tv25.commit();
    tv25.commit();
     }
```

Получается, что при сохранении должно получится два файла `MyPTv` и `MyOfice`. Когда подгружаю данные во-втором активити, `loadText()` должен загрузить данные из  `MyPTv`, а `loadTexts()` из `MyOfice`. Но  подгружаются данные из последнего сохраненного, во все TextViews в которые я указываю

```
 private void loadText() {
    if ( orglastgraf.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        MyPTv = getSharedPreferences("MyPTv", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = MyPTv.getString(SAVED_Tv20, "");
        String savedTexts = MyPTv.getString(SAVED_Tv21, "");
        String savedTextss = MyPTv.getString(SAVED_Tv22, "");
        String savedTextsss = MyPTv.getString(SAVED_Tv23, "");
        orglastgraf.setText(savedText);
        daytimelastprib.setText(savedTexts+" "+savedTextss);
        timezakr.setText(savedTextsss);         
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Данные были автоматически вставлены. Повторная вставка запрещена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
private void loadTexts() {
    if ( dataoffice.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        sPrefss = getSharedPreferences("MyOfice", MODE_APPEND);
        String savedT = sPrefss.getString(SAVED_T, "");
        String savedTs = sPrefss.getString(SAVED_Tv, "");
        String savedTss = sPrefss.getString(SAVED_Tv2, "");
        dataoffice.setText(savedT+" "+savedTs);
        timeoffice.setText(savedTss);    
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Данные были автоматически вставлены. Повторная вставка запрещена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Почему при загрузки данные не вставляются в свои `TextViews`?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Не могли бы по точнее выразить свою проблему. Что именно у вас не получается

Comment: Чему равно значение `SAVED_Tv20`, `SAVED_Tv21` и т.д.? И не нужно создавать столько экземпляров `SharedPreferences.Editor`. Достаточно одного, добавить в него все значения и сделать один коммит.

Comment: У вас не правильно стоят ключи в методе loadTexts() и вообще это просто не читабельно с такими названиями. Вам просто ни кто не захочет помогать лишь взглянув на это. Почитайте книгу чистый код, а потом продолжите изучать программирование.

Comment: Прибрался в коде и подправил описание.